# Отлючается сокет на node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

Есть сайт http://reallot.kz/ 
На нем реализовано обновление цены с помощью сокета. Веб сокет сделан на node.js . Сокет запускаем, работает, все нормльно, но через какое то время сокет отключается. Хостинг построен на VPS. Запускаем сокет через выполнить команду, открывается доп окно, показывая что сокет работает, как только эту вкладку закрываем сокет отключается. Есть спецы кто может помочь?

Comment: День добрый. Вы же понимаете, что без кода мы вам помочь не можем? (: Приведите код по созданию сокета, обработке запросов и пример того, как вы запускаете скрипт.

Comment: Может обговорим условия оплаты труда и вы глянете? Там куча кода

Comment: Боюсь, для подобного рода вопросов SO не подходит...

Comment: какой, хоть, пакет для работы с сокетами используете?